# SVG <animateTransform> is not loading when i use as a background image

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi here I added SVG as a background image the code inside the path which is `<animateTransform>` is not loading so, the SVG animation is not working. what might be the issue can anyone suggest to me.
[image]

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

/* Using svg like this which is not working */
.page_loader {
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:99999;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('http://content/uploads/preloader.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #ffa600;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="L7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
 <path fill="#fff" d="M31.6,3.5C5.9,13.6-6.6,42.7,3.5,68.4c10.1,25.7,39.2,38.3,64.9,28.1l-3.1-7.9c-21.3,8.4-45.4-2-53.8-23.3
  c-8.4-21.3,2-45.4,23.3-53.8L31.6,3.5z">
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="2s" 
         from="0 50 50"
         to="360 50 50" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
 <path fill="#fff" d="M42.3,39.6c5.7-4.3,13.9-3.1,18.1,2.7c4.3,5.7,3.1,13.9-2.7,18.1l4.1,5.5c8.8-6.5,10.6-19,4.1-27.7
  c-6.5-8.8-19-10.6-27.7-4.1L42.3,39.6z">
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="1s" 
         from="0 50 50"
         to="-360 50 50" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
 <path fill="#fff" d="M82,35.7C74.1,18,53.4,10.1,35.7,18S10.1,46.6,18,64.3l7.6-3.4c-6-13.5,0-29.3,13.5-35.3s29.3,0,35.3,13.5
  L82,35.7z">
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="2s" 
         from="0 50 50"
         to="360 50 50" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Works fine for me with animation when used as a background image.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you please make the snippet of your code

Comment: why, it's just your code. You can make a snippet if you want. Convert the SVG file to a data URL and you can use it in the snippet as a background

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good, i thought you said: "Why when i save the SVG code to file then use it as background image, the SVG animation is not worked?"

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you need to encode the `#` like so: `fill='%23fff'`. Please try using this encoder: https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs

Comment: @ManhNguyen no, I said the SVG animation **did** work when I used it as a background image.

Comment: What browser/system are you using?

Comment: I have tried it with an SVG file created from the inline code given and it works on Chrome/Edge and Firefox on WIndows 10 and on Safari on IOS 14.4. I did put a working snippet up in an answer for others to try but it was instantly downvoted so I'm removing it. It may be that your SVG file does not correspond to your inline one in some way.